# Python & Cartopy: lat / lon values ignored

Tags: python, gis, cartopy

I have encountered a problem regarding Cartopy, which seems to ignore my specification of lon- and lat-values.

Here's some Python code to explain my question:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # matplotlib.pyplot ist ein Modul zum Erzeugen von Plots
import numpy as np              # numpy ist ein Modul zur Vereinfachung numerischer Berechnungen
import xarray as xr             # xarray ist das Modul zur Definition des xarray-Konstrukts
import cartopy                  # cartopy dient zum Zeichnen von Landkarten
import cartopy.crs as ccrs      
import cartopy.util as cu       # cartopy.util wird benötigt, um ein Datenfeld zyklisch zu ergänzen, 
                                # also die erste Reihe von Werten entlang der Längengrade als letzte zu wiederholen
from cartopy.mpl.gridliner import LongitudeFormatter, LatitudeFormatter
                                # LongitudeFormatter und LatitudeFormatter werden zum Zeichnen der
                                # Gitterlinien benötigt.
import scipy.stats

def cartopymap(corners):
    [leftlon, lowerlat, rightlon, upperlat] = corners
    central_lon = (leftlon+rightlon)/2
    ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    ax.set_extent([leftlon, rightlon, lowerlat, upperlat])
    ax.coastlines(resolution='110m', linewidth=1.0)
    lontics = np.arange(leftlon-10,rightlon,20)
    lattics = np.arange(0,101,10)  # Gilt nur für Nordhemisphäre
    gl = ax.gridlines(crs=ccrs.PlateCarree(), draw_labels=True,
                  linewidth=1.5, color='gray', alpha=0.5, linestyle='--')
    gl.top_labels = False
    gl.right_labels = False
    gl.xlabel_style = {'size': 12}
    gl.ylabel_style = {'size': 12}    
    gl.xformatter = LongitudeFormatter()
    gl.yformatter = LatitudeFormatter()
    return ax

def plot_filled_contours_map(title, corners, Z, levz, colormap):
    fig = plt.figure(facecolor='1.', figsize=[10, 5])
    map = cartopymap(corners)
    data, lon = cu.add_cyclic_point(Z.values, Z.lon.values)
    lat = Z.lat
    CP = map.contourf(lon, lat, data, levz, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), cmap=colormap, extend='both')
    map.coastlines()
    cbar = plt.colorbar(CP, ax=map, aspect=50, fraction=0.1)
    cbar.ax.tick_params(labelsize=10)
    plt.title(title, y=1.1, fontsize=14)
    
ncfile = "monthly_v_2018.nc"
tempdata = xr.open_dataset(ncfile)
levz = [-20, -17.5, -15, -12.5, -10, -7.5, -5, 5, 7.5, 10, 12.5, 15, 17.5, 20]
colormap = 'seismic'
temp = tempdata.sel(time="2018-07-01", plev="3e+04")
plotcorners = [-120, -30, 120, 80]
plot_filled_contours_map('Monthly mean of meridional wind on 300 hPa', plotcorners, temp.v, levz, colormap)
```

... resulting in

[image]

...which is not what I would expect, given the plotcorners as above

Comment: there are many undefined variables in the example code.
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: As said, this is impossible to answer if others can't replicate it. It could be that your understanding of `set_extent` is incorrect, it uses a Geodetic projection as the default , see for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77006676/1755432

Comment: I have updated the code. One more question: How can I upload the input file? It's ~2 MB in size.

Comment: Problem is solved, Rutger's comment was really helpful.